# Select a row in a IG when dialog closed

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

How to select a specific row in a IG after dialog closed? In modal dialog users can update data in a table.

I set items values with DA when row selection change.

When dialog closed I have DA with that code:

```js
apex.region("jednostkiRaport").call("setSelectedRecords", []);
```

Next step I'd like to select changed row to set updated values in my items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code block to first get the record you want to be selected by its primary key value(by sequence nr, id etc.) then `setSelectedRecords` would work.

```
var record = apex.region("gridId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model.getRecord("4551");

apex.region("gridId").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").setSelectedRecords([record],true);
```

Note: gridId should be replaced with your grid's static ID.

Another Note: You can use your browser's console to execute this code block.

Comment: I have a IG with pagination and yours code work only with records from current pagination, is it any way to select row from another page of paginatnion?